# Edit link on hovering

Tags: html, css

How to show an edit link on the profile picture just like the one on facebook but positioned at the right-top corner of the image?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="topgrid">
     <a href="#"><img src="C:/images/users/image1.png"/>               
        <span class="image" id="image">Edit Picture</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.image {
color:#033;
font-size:12px;
background:#FFF;
display:none;
top:0;
right:0;
width:80px;
position:absolute;
}

.topgrid:hover .image{
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}

.topgrid {
background-color:gray;
height:100px;
width:100px;
position:relative;
}
```

​
I am here using the fixed width of the span element, but when I don't specify the width of the span element, the element doesn't appears at the absolute top right-corner . So i have to adjust the right property as:

```
right:13%;
```

which is not the standard way to do it. I need your valuable suggestions!

I am also attaching the tried out fiddle here!

http://jsfiddle.net/nQvEW/81/

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: @SumitGera: Yes, you should. Please read the link in the above comment, to see what you need to include in your question.

Comment: Have you read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#question)

Comment: Use the "edit" link on your OP!

Comment: @Munchies. I have inserted the tried code.. Please help me out..

Comment: I have edited the code alot, the "Edit Picture" text is still at the border of the parent div.

Comment: Do you want the Edit link centered on the top ? Because it already looks positioned at the top right corner.

Comment: @sumit can you please provide the image you are using on <a> tag. Update in you question so i can use that and try to solve your issue ASAP.

Comment: @SumitGera i have updated the answer .Check the bottom of the answer for the new Fiddle.Hope that solves your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking for ?

The span element has **no fixed width and remains in the top-right corner**!

```
.image {
color:#033;
font-size:12px;
background:#FFF;
display:none;
width:auto;
float:right;
}

.topgrid:hover .image{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
cursor:pointer;
}

.topgrid {
background-color:gray;
height:100px;
width:100px;
position:relative;
}
```

​
**Here's the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6Yw6/15/**

What i have done is :

1. made the span width to **auto** and gave **float:right**.
2. Removed **position:absolute;top:0;right:0** property from span. Add them if it causes browser compatibility problems

You can also do

```
.image{
   background:transparent;
   color:white;
   font-weight:500;
}
```

to make it look good!

Here's the new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6Yw6/15/) as per your request! Tell me if there's anymore changes to be made.

Comment: Thats very close to what I have been looking for, but the width of "Edit Picture" element should be constricted to the "Edit Picture" string and should be on the top-right corner. Though nice effort!

Comment: @SumitGera I have updated the answer with the new Fiddle .You can find the link at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Thank You. This exactly meets my requirements except for some custom styles. I just have to implement on my website.

Comment: Maybe i could help you with those custom styles

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6Yw6/2/)

css:

```
.image {
  position:relative;
  color:#033;
  font-size:12px;
  background:#FFF;
  display:none;
  top:0;
}

.topgrid:hover .image{
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  width:auto;
  background:none;
  top:-205px;
}

.topgrid {
  text-align:right;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  margin:20px;
}​
```

Comment: I have attached the fiddle and this instance works for the span element having fixed width, but the span element has no fixed width! Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

First step is to have the image be a background image rather than a straight-up `<img>` tag. This will allow you to add child nodes.

Add one such child node: the edit link. Make it appear where you want it, ignore the "only when hovering" part for now.

When you're ready, add `display:none`. Then, in the `:hover` style for the *container*, (ie. `#container:hover>#editlink`), add `display:block`. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the dynamic html tag generations every time on hover